# CKEditor image properties tabs disappear

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor

I'm having an issue with CKEditor regarding image properties. Spent many hours investigating this but ended up without solution.

I'm using Drupal 7 with the latest CKEditor AND IMCE.

When I click on the image icon on CKEditor tool bar, the image properties popup window came up but I was looking at the "advanced" tab is not showing up.  No tab show up at all.

Is there any configuration that I have to apply in order to show up the tabs in the image properties?

Comment: Maybe it has a permission error of IMCE. Go to IMCE settings and check if only administrator has permission to upload images. I had this problem with wysiwyg and imce.

Comment: I did checked the IMCE permission.  I changed around the IMCE permission but still no luck.

Comment: IMCE permissions and IMCE settings? Because in IMCE you declare Profiles with permissions. By default IMCE provides permissions only for Admins.

Answer (score 0):

you can try by reinstalling with ckeditor - 7.x-1.16 and imce - 7.x-1.9,

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I got this trouble when use cdn version of ckeditor instead of local.

To fix it download latest ckeditor from official site http://ckeditor.com/download. I have downloaded full version. Then copy files to **/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor**. Before you copy here must be only 1 file with name COPY_HERE.txt. After copy folders adapters, lang... etc.

Then go to the global settings of the ckeditor **admin/config/content/ckeditor/editg** and set path to the local ckeditor library like this: **%m/ckeditor**. Save settings and check if advanced tabs exist now.